# How can I find the index list of faces that are illuminated from a lightsource?

Tags: python, lighting

I'd like to use bpy to determine the faces of an object that are illuminated by a lightsource and store their indexes for further processing.

I've tried using `object.ray_cast` but, as I understand, it only computes for other objects shadowing the one from which the vertices are specified, whereas what I'm trying to do is obtaining all the faces of an object that are in direct sight of the lightsource, without being shadowed by other parts the same object.

This sounds fairly doable for Blender to me, is there any way to do this?